# How to use horovod for allreduce operations on normal values？

Tags: python, tensorflow, mpi, distributed-computing

Horovod can easily calculate the gradient of tensorflow. Can we use horovod to calculate ordinary values?For example:

```
import horovod.tensorflow as hvd
import numpy as np
hvd.init()
hvd_r=int(hvd.rank())
#each process compute a small part of something and then compute the average etc.
test_array=np.random.rand(100,100,100)
#compute a small part
x=np.mean(test_array[hvd_r*10:(hvd_r+1)*(10),:,:])
#compute the average for all processes
y=hvd.sth(x)
#only one process print out the result
if(hvd_r==0):
    print("mean of the big array is %f"%y)
```

Comment: why did you set the MPI tag ?

Comment: Because horovod is based upon MPI, and I was not able to set a new horovod tag..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import horovod.keras as hvd
import numpy as np
hvd.init()
hvd_r=int(hvd.rank())
#each process compute a small part of something and then compute the average etc.
test_array=np.random.rand(100,100,100)
#compute a small part
x=np.mean(test_array[hvd_r*10:(hvd_r+1)*(10),:,:])
#compute the average for all processes
y=hvd.allreduce(x)
#only one process print out the result
if(hvd_r==0):
    print("mean of the big array is %f"%y)
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 10, change it to

```
y=hvd.allreduce(x)
```

It will give you desired result.